# flutter - is it possible to use flutter code to represent something similar to this?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to show the following with flutter?

As far as I know, only the corners of a container can be rounded off. I asked myself whether it is also possible to display something similar to the one in the picture below using flutter codes?

Since I don't even begin to know how and if you could do something like that, I am very curious about the answers, but I reckon that it could possibly be complicated.

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 0):

YES!
It can be done by using path in flutter.
You can do each shape separately and then put them in a row.
[Read this well organized article about path in flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0), then you can build all types of path. good luck :)

Comment: All right, thank you both, I already thought that it would not be so easy ^^ unfortunately that is still too high for me, but thank you very much, so at least I know the direction in which I have to inform myself :-)

Comment: @ɢʜᴏsᴛ You are very welcome, take good care of yourself and have the best time with flutter. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I see two main ways to approach this. Either use an image with the design from above, and use a `Stack` widget to add the text and icon on top.

The second option would be to use `customPainter` or possibly `paths` to make your custom shape. The documentation is here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html